# kubectl diff output to show only file names?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there a way to run `kubectl diff -f .` in that way so that output shows only file names that would be changed with `kubectl apply -f .` and not every single diff line...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use, something as below, here `KUBECTL_EXTERNAL_DIFF` is an env variable, to use a custom `diff` program with custom flags. So, basically, here we are telling `kubectl` to use `diff -qr` for displaying the difference. By default, kubectl use `diff -u -N`.

```
KUBECTL_EXTERNAL_DIFF='diff -qr' kubectl diff -f .
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Also, I've found out we can use colored output with: `KUBECTL_EXTERNAL_DIFF='colordiff -N -u' kubectl diff -f`